# org.mapstruct don't work with a base class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok, mapstruct

I have 2 classes. My base class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class BaseRequest {

   @NotNull
   @JsonProperty("dateTransaction")
   private String dateTransaction;

   @NotNull
   @JsonProperty("hourTransaction")
   private String hourTransaction;

}
```

And my other class. This class extends BaseRequest class.

```
public class AddClass extends BaseRequest {

   @Setter
   @Getter
   private String additionalData60;

}
```

And When I try create a mapper to cast my AddClass to OtherClass:

```
@Component
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
public interface OtherMapper{

   @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "hourTransaction", target = "timeTransaction"),
        @Mapping(source = "dateTransaction", target = "dateTransaction"),
        @Mapping(source = "additionalData60", target = "additionalData60"),
   })
   OtherClass toOtherClass(AddClass addClass);

}
```

When I run my build I received this error:

> Error:(22,13) java: No property named "dateTransaction" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "null"?

Comment: What happens if you add the getters manually instead of using Lombok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapStruct works without issues with Lombok.

However, if you have upgraded to Lombok 1.18.16 as per the [Lombok Changelog](https://projectlombok.org/changelog) then you need to add

`lombok-mapstruct-binding`

In Gradle:

```
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.1.0"
```

```
<path>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</path>
```